# $http Post doesnt send data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Im truing to send a email but for some reason cant send the data in my http post, in my php var_dump data says array dont have any proeprties, i dont receive the data in my php script.

network sent data:

[image]

My controler code:

```
$http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'php/admin-mail.php',
          data: claimDataService.get(),
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} ,
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available

            console.log("sucess");
            console.log(response);
          }, function errorCallback(response) {

            console.log("errors");
            console.log(response);
          });
```

My Service:

```
var claimDataService = angular.module('claimDataService', []);

claimDataService.factory('claimDataService', function() {
 var claimData = {}
 function set(data) {
   claimData = data;
 }
 function get() {
  return claimData;
 }

 return {
  set: set,
  get: get,
 }

});
```

admin-mail.php:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

return $_POST['myData'];


}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what `claimDataService.get()` returns?

Comment: Could you also post the service code for `claimsDataService.get()`?

Comment: basically it only returns a object example {"info": {type....}..

Comment: you're showing the response.. it might be a problem in your backend as well. Can you show the payload in the request to see what are you actually sending ?

Comment: Post your AngularJS service code, it's important for us to understand what `claimDataService` looks like.

Comment: Hi there guys, i just updated the answer, i looks like it already sends the data, but when i vardump the info in my php file it says that there arent no proerties on the array

Comment: @Pedro you're sending a form, you need to access each property of the form from $_POST, like $_POST['personal_information']. Did you try that ? Are you trying to send  a json ? If so, change the content-type header

Comment: In my php script i inserted "return   var_dump($_POST);" to see the data, but in my network tab response, it doenst show nothing

Comment: @Pedro I posted my answer. did change content-type to `applcation/json` work for you?

Comment: I see tthat in the payload data is being sent, but i cant understand why in my php script is not returning nothing

Comment: @LuisEstevez After i var dump it gives me a array(0) {}
No Properties

Comment: Your php script should have `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` You can dump that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've found your problem, if you're trying to your data as JSON you must have

```
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

Then have your PHP script to get the input

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```